# Opening the Windows 8 touch keyboard

Tags: java, windows, keyboard, swt, on-screen-keyboard

Does somebody know how open the "windows 8 touch keyboard" from an SWT application?

I want to open the "touch keyboard" when the SWT input get focus, like other native applications do.

Perhaps there is a particular "style" to use, when instantiating the `Text` class?

Something like:

```
text = new Text(shell, SWT.OPEN_TOUCH_KEYBOARD);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the on screen keyboard by calling

```
Program.launch("osk.exe");
```

when the `Text` gains focus.

That'll make your application very platform (and even version) specific, so make sure that you're running an OS that has the on screen keyboard available.

Comment: Thanks Baz! Yes, this is a possibility, but i thought that eclipse guys had introduce a new "style" for work with the virtual keyboard, for the os that have it

Comment: @zaquas Not that I'm aware of. They can be pretty slow when it comes to adopting new technologies. They've only just added support for hi-dpi displays.

Comment: I think you are right... unfortunately, thanks however